I am using BigQuery Studio and my simple query is taking too long
My query is simple but it is taking so long. I am new using BigQuery Studio, but I suspect of my spreadsheet table that I have imported to BigQuery.
This is the query:
WITH MaxStepsPerDay AS (
  SELECT 
    Date,
    MAX(Steps) AS Max_Steps
  FROM `soy-codex-441615-u9.Women_wellness.minutes_Steps_March_to_april`
  WHERE Id = 1503960366
  GROUP BY Date
)
SELECT 
  ms.Date,
  ms.Max_Steps,
  original.Time
FROM MaxStepsPerDay ms
JOIN `soy-codex-441615-u9.Women_wellness.minutes_Steps_March_to_april` original
  ON ms.Date = original.Date AND ms.Max_Steps = original.Steps
WHERE original.Id = 1503960366;

And the error message is this:
Resources exceeded during query execution: Google Sheets service overloaded for spreadsheet id: 1J2zfUFbAWPtouinGNXbFZ_lmDvIT3k_gwGRsllRbQS0
I would be glad if someone could help me with this,
Thanks!

Pull data in BQ temp table then apply joins as follows. This will reduce complexity

BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE MaxStepsPerDay AS (
    SELECT Date,
    MAX(Steps) AS Max_Steps
  FROM `soy-codex-441615-u9.Women_wellness.minutes_Steps_March_to_april`
  WHERE Id = 1503960366
  GROUP BY Date
);


CREATE TEMP TABLE minutes_Steps_March_to_april AS (
SELECT DATE, 
       Steps,
       Time,
       FROM `soy-codex-441615-u9.Women_wellness.minutes_Steps_March_to_april` 
       WHERE Id = 1503960366
);


SELECT 
  ms.Date,
  ms.Max_Steps,
  original.Time
FROM MaxStepsPerDay ms
JOIN minutes_Steps_March_to_april original
  ON ms.Date = original.Date AND ms.Max_Steps = original.Steps;

END;

